# Gambler's Ruin Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two gamblers, A and B, initially have capital 7 and  13 respectively. At each round of the 
game, player A wins 1 from B with probability p, or loses 1 to B with probability q = 1 - p. 
Assume that 0 < p < 1 and that different rounds of game are independent. A and B play until one of them is ruined. Find the probability of each of the following events:

(a) the event that there is at least one gambler whose capital has ever been 4

(b) the event that the capital of gambler A has ever been 4

(c) the event that the capital of each gambler has ever been 4.

I have thought of using the following formula for gambler A :
[image]

As for gambler B , after replacing k by a - k , p by q , q by p, we have :
[image]

I somehow tried to change a = 20 to a = 16 but somehow the numbers just don't add up. What do you guys think ?

Comment: I can tell you right away that (a) has answer $100\%$.

Comment: yea thinking about it, one of their capital MUST be 4 throughout in order for either one of them to be ruined.

Comment: By the way, for (b), as you replaced $20$ with $16$, did you also remember to replace $7$ with $3$?

Comment: Yea I totally forgotten about A's capital ! Yea now it is all starting to make sense !Thanks Arthur !